# Combination of pair elements within lists in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations

I'm trying to obtain the pair combinations of elements (list elements) within a DataFrame. I need to keep the first column to determine the original 'group' of the element pairs but splitting the element lists into element pairs in new rows.

I would have the following case:

|  | Group | X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Group 1 | A,B,C |
| 1 | Group 2 | D,E |
| 2 | Group 3 | F,G,H,I |

And the output needs to be something like:

|  | Group | X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Group 1 | A,B |
| 1 | Group 1 | A,C |
| 2 | Group 1 | B,C |
| 3 | Group 2 | D,E |
| 4 | Group 3 | F,G |
| 5 | Group 3 | F,H |
| 6 | Group 3 | F,I |
| 7 | Group 3 | G,H |
| 8 | Group 3 | G,I |
| 9 | Group 3 | H,I |

I would like to keep the `Group` column belonging to every combination. I don't know how to iterate through a DataFrame and keep that `Group` values in each row.

Comment: As an idea for you to explore: turn your X column into several columns and run combinations from intertools on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to find all combinations of elements of length 2 for each row in the dataframe. This will give you a list exploded using [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) as follows:

```py
from itertools import combinations

df['X'] = df['X'].apply(lambda l: list(combinations(l, 2)))
df = df.explode('X')
```

Result:

```
     Group    X
0  Group 1  A,B
0  Group 1  A,C
0  Group 1  B,C
1  Group 2  D,E
2  Group 3  F,G
2  Group 3  F,H
2  Group 3  F,I
2  Group 3  G,H
2  Group 3  G,I
2  Group 3  H,I
```

Answer (score 1):

Shaido’s answer is great, but I want to add something

- 1. create a toy dataset

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import itertools
basedata = pd.DataFrame({"Group":['Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3'],
"x":['A,B,C', 'D,E', 'F,G,H,I']})
basedata
```

[image]

- 2. split character by ","

```py
basedata['x'] = basedata['x'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
basedata
```

[image]

- 3.use itertools generate combinations

```py
basedata['x'] = basedata['x'].apply(lambda x: list(itertools.combinations(x, 2)))
basedata
```

[image]

- 4. use pandas explode function to explode "x"

```py
basedata = basedata.explode("x")
basedata
```

[image]

- 5 transform set to character

```py
basedata['x'] = basedata['x'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
basedata
```

[image]

get more information,you can click those links:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations